# ViewPager showing stretched portrait image

Tags: java, android

I want to display images slideshow using Glide with ViewPager. Problem is, portrait images are displayed stretched even after setting `wrap_content` attribute.

My layout is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.maninder.sportsfitvns.AboutMyWorks.MyWorks">


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/PSviewPager"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
```

and main code

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_slideshow);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        viewPager= findViewById(R.id.PSviewPager);
  //      viewPager2= findViewById(R.id.PSviewPager2);
        final MyNewAdapter adapter;
        final Handler handler;
        final Runnable runnable;
        Timer timer;

        adapter = new MyNewAdapter(this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
//        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

        handler = new Handler();

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                int i = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                if (i == adapter.images.length - 1) {

                    i = 0;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(i, true);

                } else {

                    i++;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(i, true);
                }
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                handler.post(runnable);
            }
        }, 4000, 4000);
```

How can I display a portrait image in it's original form without being stretched, or any other possible/efficient way of displaying images from url.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: make the height and width of your ViewPager match_parent ..and also post the layout of the viewpager..

Comment: tried,no change.. and i did posted viewpager layout

Comment: the layout of the fragment of the viewpager...post the layout which has the image

Comment: And where is the glide part? Try setting .fitCenter() there